# How to check whether a certain character in string comes after another character?

Tags: javascript, string, function

Given a string `aaabbbcccooeellmmzzz` how can I count the number of characters that comes after 'm'.
For example in this case it should return 5 (i.e oozzz);

Note: Here o and z characters come after 'm' in alphabetical order not about their index position after m.

So i want to count the characters (n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z) as many times they appear in the string.

Sample Input : `aaabbbcccooeellmmmzzz` 
Sample Output: **5**

Comment: please hightlight why. i see no `'oozzz'`.

Comment: Your string contains three **m** characters and it does not contain the sequence **oozzz**. What exactly should be happening - do you want to take everthing after the *first* **m**? Or after the last **m**? Or what exactly?

Comment: Just updated the question so you can understand it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `substring` to remove everything from the start to the index of the last occurrence of the character, then get the length:

```js
let character = 'm';
let str = 'aaabbbcccooeellmmmzzz';

let res = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(character) + 1).length;
console.log(res)
```